# Why "name 'cursor' is not defined" when pyodbc cursor is in main()?

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm running a Python program, condensed below, from the command line, and it gives me an error (`name 'cursor' is not defined`) and points to the `cursor.fetchmany()` row near the bottom. However, the program runs as desired if I move the first two rows of `main()`, the `conn` and `cursor` assignments, above and outside of `main()` into the body of the program. Why doesn't this work when I assign `cursor` inside `main()`? I'd love to understand whether this is just a quirk of the pyodbc library, or there is a better way to get it to work from inside `main()`, or it's actually okay to leave the assignments in the body of the program.

```
import pyodbc
import csv
#   ...other modules...

def main():
    conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN=abcxyz, autocommit=True)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
#   ...sys.argv assignments and validation...
    pull_data(query_file, start_date, end_date, out_file)

def pull_data(query_file, start_date, end_date, out_file):
#   ...prepare query as string, date range as list...
    for date in list_dates:
        cursor.execute(query, date)
        append_rows(out_file)

def append_rows(out_file):
    with open(out_file, 'a', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        while True:
            results = cursor.fetchmany(chunk_size)
            if not results:
                break
            for result in results:
                writer.writerow(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `conn` is local to `main`, a class would be a much better idea

Comment: I think I agree -- if I want to guarantee the DB connection is closed in the event of an error, I'd either have to pass both `conn` and `cursor` to just about every function, or I can make an object that can always call a db_close() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because cursor is not defined in `append_rows()` or `pull_data()`. You're defining it in `main()`, so it's only accessible in `main()`.

The best way to fix this is probably to pass the cursor object to `append_rows()` and `pull_data()`.

Comment: Does this mean I need to pass `cursor` as an additional argument to `pull_data()` and again to `append_rows()`?

Comment: @RobinFiveWords Yup. You could define it outside of `main()` and it'll be in the global scope, but it's generally better to keep things in as local of a scope as you can.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that you're getting an error with `cursor` not being defined, is because it doesn't exists in your functions. Variables only exist in the scope they are defined in.

When you defined `cursor` outside of `main`, it was declared as a global variable, meaning that it will be accessible in all scopes of the script.

Try:

```
import pyodbc
import csv
#   ...other modules...

def main():
    # Since conn and cursor are being declared here, they only exist within the scope of this function, not other functions that are called.
    conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN=abcxyz, autocommit=True)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
#   ...sys.argv assignments and validation...
    # make sure we give the cursor to pull_data so it will exist in its scope!
    pull_data(query_file, start_date, end_date, out_file, cursor)

def pull_data(query_file, start_date, end_date, out_file, cursor):
#   ...prepare query as string, date range as list...
    for date in list_dates:
        cursor.execute(query, date)
        # Pass the cursor to append_rows
        append_rows(out_file, cursor)

# cursor is actually passed to the append_rows function. Now it exists in this scope
def append_rows(out_file, cursor):
    with open(out_file, 'a', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        while True:
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            for result in results:
                writer.writerow(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would also recommend that you read https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/5249060.